# Repeater Inside Pivot Control (Or Hub Control) Is Undefined

Tags: windows-8.1, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I am having trouble putting a `Repeater` inside a `Repeater` inside a `PivotItem`, when I try to access the `Repeater` via `JavaScript`, the `winControl` property is always null, am I missing something?

### HTML:

```
<div id="divContent" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Pivot" data-win-options="{title: 'Header', selectedIndex: 0}">
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.PivotItem" data-win-options="{'header': 'Repeated Data'}">
        <div id="rptData" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
    rptData.winControl.data = getData();
}
```

`rptData` returns the `DIV` Element, but `winControl` is undefined.

The same thing happens when using a `Repeater` inside a `Hub` control in Windows 8.1 (none phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rptData.winControl is undefined because WinJS did not still process the element. WinJS.UI.processAll() is async function.
You can process it manually and use it when it's processed:

```
WinJS.UI.process(rptData).then(function () {
        rptData.winControl.data = getData();        
});
```